# How to do calculated Attributes in a database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I hope you can help me to understand how to solve my issue. Bases is the creation of a database where working hours of employees should be stored.
With these hours a little math is involved and the combination of database+math seems to be a problem.

I want to store the theoretically workable hours of an employee:
52(weeks a year)*40 hours a week = 2080 Minus holiday etc -> 1900 hours expected time yearly.
His actually worked time would go up by 8 hours each day until he reaches 1900, what would already be an issue. Meaning i dont really know how to implemnt that.

But the problem continues:
This time shall be split between 12 months equally. Okay so 1900 devided by 12 in 12 different columns... sounds stupid but now he reports sick in february and his actual time decreases within this month and accordingly his overall working time decreases as well.

Also there are things like parttime workers or people taking a sabbathical and also these hours need to be conncted to different projects (another table in same db)

In excel this issue was relatively easy to solve but with a pure db Iam kinda lost as how to approach it.

So 2 questions: is something like this even possible in a Mysql DB (i somehow doubt it).
And how would i do it?( in the db or with some additional software/frontend)

Comment: It is quite normal to to these things. You save in one column his starting time and in antother when he ends. the difference tells you exactly how much he work and when you summ up and group this by month you got how much he actually worked every month. You can do lot of things and use almost evberything what mysql has. you need of course more comuns, one for the workerid and one atleast for comments and one id for what this working day was, for example paid holidays, sic and so on. Start with your tables and don'zt worry you can alter almost anything

Comment: Yes, design the table with the data first.  Then worry about the math.  And finally worry about the layout (eg, 12 monthly columns).  These 3 steps will help you focus on one thing at a time, and the implementation will actually involve 3 steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to make a DTR system (Daily Time Reoords).  I do recommend to design the database that will cater flexible scenarios to all types of employees.  A common ground of storing information (date and time) that be able to calculate their working hours of these people.

You worry about the algorithms later it will follow based on your database design.